# How to find styling css file in Visual Studio. Adding space between radio button radiobuttonlist with label

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, styling, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to add space between radiobuttonlist.

I see the aspx markup code, CssClass="radiobuttonlist" but when I use Ctrl + Shift + F, and type in .radiobuttonlist with Entire Solution, I can't find the css file that contains the definition. Strange, I found this

```
input[type=radio],
.radio{
    margin: -1px 10px 0 0;
}
```

I am not sure what are the 4 values stands for but I tried making changes like 
margin: 10px 10px 0 0; but not having any luck in adding spaces after the radio button label.

I also see another CssClass definition in the aspx like CssClass="radiobuttonlist showGender" but I am not sure how showGender is used in the css file or aspx.

Is there another way to find in Visual Studio where the CssClass="radiobuttonlist" is defined. Any help with adding spaces after the label would be greatly appreciated. Been googling and trying out different values but no success after a few hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to the following and it is working.

```
.radio{
      margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px;
}
```